# Check If Metatable Is Read Only

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to find a way to check if a Metatable is readonly or not

for example

```
local mt = metatable(game)
if mt == "readonly" do
print("Attempt to modify Metatables")
end
```

I hope there is a way to do this for Roblox, so I can prevent GUI tampering

Comment: Add a new field in your table, if the field does not exits Lua will use `__newindex` to add in your table. Read-only table will return an error.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but you can protect a metatable by adding a field `__metatable` to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getmetatable()` to see if the contents of a metatable are protected.

Example:

```
local mt = getmetatable(game)
if mt ~= nil and type(mt) ~= "table" then -- not perfect, as __metatable could be set to {}
    print("This metatable is protected!")
end
```

Alternatively if you are looking to see if the table itself is read-only, you will need to check two behaviors

1. What happens when you attempt to add a value to the table
2. What happens when you attempt to change a value in the table.

Example of read-only table:

```
local protected_table = {'1', '2', '3'}
local table  = setmetatable({}, {-- create a dumby table with a metatable
    __index = function(_, k)
        return protected_table[k]-- access protected table
    end,
    __newindex = function()
        error('This value is read-only.')
    end,
    __pairs = function(_)
        return function(_, k)
            return next(protected_table, k)
        end
    end,
    __metatable = false,
})
```

Examples of possible interactions:

```
table[4] = "4" -- read-only error will be generated by _newindex setting

table[1] = "0" -- read-only error will be generated by _newindex setting

first = table[1] -- will retrieve first value of protected_table
```